# How to set different ContextMenu for different cells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a `DataGridView` with two types of cells, different by backcolor (red/green).
I would like to set a `ContextMenu` for this DataGridView, but I want it to be different for red cells and for green cells. Is there a way of doing so?

And as a second question, is there a way to assign a `ToolTip` for the `DataGridViewCells`, and again differ from the red/green cells?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I noticed that I can not only add the ContextMenuStrip in the DataGridView properties, but also when I get to the exact cells using `foreach row`, then `foreach` `cell` in `row` and set the ContextMenuStrip to the exact cell.

Answer (score 0):

Add tool tip in grid view -

```
asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="short_comment">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("short_comment") %>' ToolTip ='<%# Bind("longer_comment") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```